# react-native-i18n: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNI18n.languages')

Tags: javascript, react-native

So, I want to setup multilanguage support for my app. On the base of react-native. However, when looking at i18n solution it pops up an error:

[image]

I followed the installation step on https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n, everything installed and got linked ok, without errors. Tried to setup most basic sample on completely new project. The "App.js" file looks as follows:

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n'
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{I18n.t('greeting')}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

I18n.fallbacks = true

I18n.translations = {
  en: {
    greeting: 'Hi!'
  },
  fr: {
    greeting: 'Bonjour!'
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to run it on emulator, the systems pops that error. Driving me nuts at this point. Any known solutions I have missed at this point?

Comment: I think your setup hasnt finish, check the docs: https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n#manual-setup

Answer (score 2):

In your project, execute:

```
$ react-native link
```

and reboot.

See:

- https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n#manual-setup
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#step-2